# Ratio between $k$th highest number among $n$ and $n+1$ samples

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $n\geq k$ be fixed positive integers, and let $X$ be a distribution on $[0,1]$ that is *not* the constant $0$ distribution. Let $E_n$ denote the expected value of the $k$th highest value among $n$ independent samples from $X$, and $E_{n+1}$ the expected value of the $k$th highest value among $n+1$ independent samples from $X$. What is $\inf\frac{E_n}{E_{n+1}}$ in terms of $n,k$ over all such distributions $X$?

For $k=1$, the answer is $\frac{n}{n+1}$, as is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1197302/193063).

For $X$ being the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, the answer is $\frac{(n+1-k)(n+2)}{(n+2-k)(n+1)}$.

Some partial progress: We can show (similarly to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1197302/193063)) that $$(n+1-k)E_{n+1}\leq (n+1)E_n,$$ which yields $\frac{E_n}{E_{n+1}}\geq\frac{n+1-k}{n+1}$. Is this bound tight? I've tried to calculate for the distribution $X$ which is $0$ with probability $1-\epsilon$ and $1$ with probability $\epsilon$, but the estimation is complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps surprisingly, your bound is tight. Consider your distribution $X$. The probability that the $k$th largest value among $n$ is $1$ is exactly
$$
\sum_{t=k}^n \binom{n}{t} \epsilon^t (1-\epsilon)^{n-t} = \binom{n}{k} \epsilon^k + O(\epsilon^{k+1}).
$$
Hence
$$
\frac{E_n}{E_{n+1}} = \frac{\binom{n}{k} \epsilon^k + O(\epsilon^{k+1})}{\binom{n+1}{k}\epsilon^k + O(\epsilon^{k+1})} = \frac{\binom{n}{k}}{\binom{n+1}{k}} + O(\epsilon) = \frac{n+1-k}{n+1} + O(\epsilon).
$$